# Beginner Django admin question - has no attribute 'date_hierarchy'

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm just learning Django, and I'm trying to set up the admin area for a new project.

I'm getting the following error:

```
type object 'StopInline' has no attribute 'date_hierarchy'
```

Here is the model:

```
from django.db import models

class Line(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Lap(models.Model):
    line = models.ForeignKey(Line)
    order = models.IntegerField()

class Stop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    line = models.ForeignKey(Line)
    lap = models.ForeignKey(Lap)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    departsHour = models.IntegerField()
    departsMinute = models.IntegerField()
```

And here is the admin.py:

```
from schedule.models import Line, Stop 
from django.contrib import admin

class StopInline(admin.TabularInline):  
    model = Stop
    extra = 3

class LineAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):  
    model = Line    
    inlines = [StopInline]

admin.site.register(Line, StopInline)
```

I don't have anything related to a date, so I'm not sure what's going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
admin.site.register(Stop, StopInline) # UNNECESSARY, SEE BELOW
admin.site.register(Line, LineAdmin)
```

should do it. `register` expects models and `ModelAdmin`s. You were trying to register to admin `Line` with `StopInline` which confused it.

**EDIT** I realized this about 45 seconds afterwards. You don't need to register StopInline since it's 'included' in LineAdmin.

Comment: Changing it to just `admin.site.register(Line, LineAdmin)` worked though. Thanks!

Comment: Gah! Don't register `Stop` - my fault.